# fetching data from different table for particular record (codeigniter)

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables in my SQL which are given following

Task Table:

```
id(pk)
title
workspaceid(fk of workspace id)
userid
description
esthours
```

Milestone Table:

```
id
taskid(fk of task table id)
workspaceid(fk of workspace id)
userid
esthours
estmin
```

Workspace Table:

```
id(pk)
userid
title
```

I want to display `title` from `Task Table`, `title` from `Workspace Table` and `esthours` and `estmin` from `Milestone Table`.

If `Milestone Tabl`e don't have `esthours` or `estmin` then it will not fetch from `Task Table`

I had done following code using join but it will fetch `esthours` from `Task Table` but it should from `Milestone Table`.

```
function getMilestone($taskid, $userid, $workspaceid, $is_master_admin) {
        $this->load->database();
       if ($is_master_admin)
           {
            $this->db->select('user.title as usertitle,workspace.title as workspacetitle,workspace.id as workspaceid,task.title as tasktitle,task.id as taskid,task.esthours as taskesthrs,milestone.esthours as milestoneesthrs, task.*'); 
        } else {
            $this->db->select('*');
        }
        $this->db->from(TASK);
        if ($is_master_admin) {
            $this->db->join(USER, 'task.userid = user.id', 'left outer');
            $this->db->join(WORKSPACE, 'task.workspaceid=workspace.id ', 'left outer');
            $this->db->join(MILESTONE,'milestone.esthours=milestone.esthours','left outer');
            //$this->db->join(TASK, ' .taskid= task.id', 'left outer');
        } else {

        }
        $this->db->where('task.id', $taskid);
        if ($is_master_admin) {
            $this->db->order_by("userid", "asc");
        } else {
            $this->db->where('userid', $userid);
        }

        $query = $this->db->get();
      // echo $this->db->last_query(); exit();

      // echo $this->db->last_query();  exit ();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with selecting your basic bits of data from MILESTONES table and then try to JOIN other tables based on those bits of data as well. For example:

```
$this->db->from(MILESTONE);
$this->db->join(USER, 'milestone.userid = user.id', 'left outer');
etc...
```